# Confusing issue on multi-key subsetting data.table within function

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to use arguments to a `data.table` to subset (and apply a mean to that subset). Basically I'll pass to the function two keys and several elements of the third key; this seems to be confusing `R`, but the operation works exactly as expected when done outside of a function environment.

Here's an example that basically gets what I'm trying to do; it returns a solution that is incorrect, while my own code produces an error (text pasted below):

```
set.seed(12345)
dt<-data.table(yr=rep(2000:2005,each=20),
               id=paste0(rep(rep(1:10,each=2),6)),
               deg=paste0(rep(1:2,60)),
               var=rnorm(120),
               key=c("yr","id","deg"))

fcn <- function(yr,ids,deg){
  dt[.(yr,ids,deg),mean(var)]
}

fcn(2004,paste0(1:3),"1")
```

This is giving an answer, but it's totally wrong (more on that in a second). If I do this by hand, there's no problem:

```
> fcn(2004,paste0(1:3),"1")
[1] 0.1262586
> dt[yr==2004&id %in% paste0(1:3)&deg=="1",mean(var)]
[1] 0.4374115
> dt[.(2004,paste0(1:3),"1"),mean(var)]
[1] 0.4374115
```

To crack what's going on, I changed the `fcn` code to:

```
fcn <- function(yr,ids,deg){
  dt[.(yr,ids,deg),]
}
```

Which yields:

```
> fcn(2004,paste0(1:3),"1")
       yr id deg        var
  1: 2000  1   1  0.5855288
  2: 2000  2   2 -0.4534972
  3: 2000  3   1  0.6058875
  4: 2000  1   2  0.7094660
  5: 2000  2   1 -0.1093033
 ---                       
116: 2005  2   2 -1.3247553
117: 2005  3   1  0.1410843
118: 2005  1   2 -1.1562233
119: 2005  2   1  0.4224185
120: 2005  3   2 -0.5360480
```

Basically, `fcn` has done *no* subsetting! Why is this happening? Really frustrated.

If I only pass one key instead of three, `dt` subsets on the middle key *only*. Weird:

```
> fcn(2004,"1","1")
       yr id deg        var
  1: 2000  1   1  0.5855288
  2: 2000  1   2  0.7094660
  3: 2000  1   1  0.5855288
  4: 2000  1   2  0.7094660
  5: 2000  1   1  0.5855288
 ---                       
116: 2005  1   2 -1.1562233
117: 2005  1   1  0.2239254
118: 2005  1   2 -1.1562233
119: 2005  1   1  0.2239254
120: 2005  1   2 -1.1562233
```

But if I pass only the middle keys to the function, it works fine:

```
fcn <- function(ids){
  dt[.(2004,ids,"1")]
}
> fcn(paste0(1:3))
     yr id deg        var
1: 2004  1   1  0.6453831
2: 2004  2   1 -0.3043691
3: 2004  3   1  0.9712207
```

---

Final edit: problem solved, but it would still be nice to know what exactly was going wrong:

Rename the arguments:

```
fcn <- function(yyr,ids,ddeg){
  dt[.(yyr,ids,ddeg),mean(var)]
}
```

Something about re-using the column names as variable names caused an issue, it seems--but I'm still not fully understanding what went wrong.

Comment: Chalk this up as case of needing to write it down to troubleshoot properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is you're using names of columns inside your `i-expression`, but expecting them to be names **outside** of the `data.table`. You can either rename the variable names in your function, or construct the join `data.table` outside and then use the fact that for single names `data.table` will always use the outside environment:

```
fcn <- function(yr,ids,deg){
  tmp = data.table(yr, ids, deg)
  dt[tmp, mean(var)]
}

fcn(2004, paste0(1:3), "1")
#[1] 0.4374115
```

See [FAQ](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.pdf) 2.12-2.13.

Comment: So this is basically an environment problem--I need to access the variables `yr` and `deg`, but `[.data.table` first looks within the scope of `dt` and stops there when it finds those columns (never moving to the function environment where the values I pass to `yr` and `deg` are stored. Missing anything?

Comment: Ahhh, so why `fcn(2004,"1","1")` was working is because only the middle argument was uniquely named (`ids` vs. `id`). Sneaky.

Comment: What's still curious to me is that I can apparently use the key name as a wildcard for that key--I thought I remembered reading in the vignettes ([here](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-keys-fast-subset.html)) that I should use `unique(key)` as that?

Comment: @MichaelChirico try `dt[.(yr), allow = T]` vs `dt[.(unique(yr))]` to see the difference

Comment: Neat. That's where the warnings were coming from--a much uglier version of `dt[.(c(2004,2004))]`.